# Can't find what the error is

Tags: c

after compiling this code,I get k=0. shouldn't it be k=0.8? 
what's wrong with the code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
void main()
{
    int x=8;
    int y=10;
    int m=6;
    float k;
    k=x/y;
    printf("k=%f",k);
}
```

Comment: because an implicit conversion in your code from float to integer to correct it:   `k=(float)x/(float)y;
    printf("k=%g",k);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type casting would be more useful and simple.

```
    int x=8;
    int y=10;
    int m=6;
    float k;
    k=(float)x/y;
    printf("k=%f",k);
```

Answer (score 2):

Although you are assigning the result of the division to a `float`, the result itself is computed in integers. This is because both operands are of type `int`.

There are multiple ways of fixing this problem - for example, by assigning the dividend to `k`, and then dividing it by the divisor, like this:

```
int x=8;
int y=10;
int m=6;
float k = x;
k /= y;
printf("k=%f",k);
```